# I have a file in the .sec path, when I convert it to mp4 or avi format with ffmpeg, the video comes out very fast

Tags: python, ffmpeg

When I convert my .sec file to mp4 or avi format using ffmpeg, the video is very fast

the pipe i use

```
ffmpeg -i 07302323_2300.sec output.mp4
```

the pipe i used took 30 minutes to 43 seconds

```
ffmpeg -i 07302323_2300.sec -r 27 -filter:v "setpts=4.1*PTS" output.mp4
```

If this is the pipe I use, I extend the time a little bit, but the video is distorted.

Any ideas on what I can do?

Comment: Copy and paste all log text from command `ffmpeg -i 07302323_2300.sec -t 10 output.mp4`

Comment: I know -t is timestamp makes this video 10 seconds wrong answer

Comment: It is not an answer. I need to see the log details. The `-t 10` was to save you some time because encoding the complete file is not necessary to see the important and required log info.

Comment: i found the solution,This is the case in my .sec file thanks @llogan

Comment: If you found a solution consider adding it as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is in my .sec file

When I ran it with ffplay, the original image was broken and it was very fast.

`-filter:v "setpts=4.1*PTS"` although this method slowed down my video a bit, it didn't work for me because of frame loss